# Panel Data Research & Development Capitalisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, finance

I am working with a panel data containing many companies' research and development expenses throughout the years.

What I would like to do is to capitalise these expenses as if they were assets. For those who are not familiar with financial terminology, I am trying to accumulate the values of each year's R&D expenses with the following ones by decaying its value (or "depreciating" it) every time period by the corresponding depreciation rate.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
           fyear      tic      rd_tot     rd_dep 
0          1979      AMFD       1.345      0.200
1          1980      AMFD       0.789      0.200
..          ..        ..          ..         ..
211339     2017       ACA       3.567      0.340
211340     2018       ACA       2.990      0.340
211341     2018      CTRM       0.054      0.234
```

Where fyear is the fiscal year, tic is the company specific letter code, rd_tot is the total R&D expenditure for the year and rd_dep is the applicable depreciation rate.

So far I was able to come up with this:

```
df['r&d_capital'] = [(df['rd_tot'].iloc[:i] * (1 - df['rd_dep'].iloc[:i]*np.arange(i)[::-1])).sum()for i in range(1, len(df)+1)]
```

However the problem is that the code just runs through the entire column without taking in consideration that the R&D expense needs to be capitalised in a company (or tic) specific way. I also tried by using .groupby(['tic]) but it did not work.

Therefore, I am trying to look for help to solve this problem, so that I can get each years R&D expenses capitalisation on a COMPANY SPECIFIC way.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What should be the output for the first 2 rows for example (as they have the same tic)?

Comment: @0buz the first row should be 1.345, whereas the second 1.865 ( = 1.345 * (1-0.2) + 0.789). 
if we assume that 1981 R&D value is 1.233, then the next capitalized value would be 2.6092 (= 1.345*(1-0.4) + 0.789*(1-0.2) + 1.233).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution breaks the initial dataframe into separate ones (one for each 'tic' group), and applies the r&d capital calculation formula on each df.
Finally, we re-construct the dataframe using `pd.concat`.

```
tic_dfs = [tic_group for _, tic_group in df.groupby('tic')]

for df in tic_dfs:
    df['r&d_capital'] = [(df['rd_tot'].iloc[:i] * (1 - df['rd_dep'].iloc[:i]*np.arange(i)[::-1])).sum() for i in range(1,len(df)+1)]


result=pd.concat([df for df in tic_dfs]).sort_index()
```

Note: `"_"` is the mask for the group name e.g. "ACA", "AMFD" etc, while `tic_group` is the actual data body.

Comment: There is only one problem with the code proposed with 0buz: the depreciation will fall into negative territory, as the machine doesn't understand that once the depreciated value reaches zero, it needs to stop taking into consideration that specific R&D expense.
So for example, if R&D expense = 3.456, the code will do the following in the time periods : t1 =  3.456 * 1, t2 =  3.456 * 0.8,  t3 = 3.456 * 0.6, t4 =  3.456 * 0.4, t5 =  3.456 * 0.2, t6 =  3.456 * 0.0, t7 =  3.456 * -0.2, t8 =  3.456 * -0.4, t9 =  3.456 * -0.6 ... and so on

Comment: Add the example to the question body. Integrate what *should* happen in the example.